# Pytest how do I use inline variables in my step arguments?

Tags: python, variables, arguments, inline, pytest

I'm writing some pytest test files which are attached to feature files that have no example or steps tables.  What I'm failing to understand is how I can use my inline variables (USER1 and USER2) which are strings within my Given, When and Then steps (simple example below for when) so that the first time the 'when' step is executed it uses John and then the second time it the 'when' step is used it uses Peter.

I've been reading these docs http://pytest-bdd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#step-arguments and its saying to use a parser?  Maybe I'm misunderstanding the docs but it isnt really clear how I can do something like the below. Maybe the users need to be in a dict? {'user1': 'John', 'user2': 'Peter'}.  I understand that using an examples table or steps table in the feature file would be great here but in this case I need to know how to do this in the background (within the pytest file only).

Thanks in advance all

```
USER1 = 'John'
USER2 = 'Peter'

@scenario('User logs in')
def test_user_logs_in():
    """User logs in to website."""
    pass

@given('I go to a website')
def I_go_to_a_website():
   Do something

@When('{user} logs in')
def user_logs_in(user):
   Do something with user1 the first time this step is used
   Do something with user2 the second time this step is used.

@then('I should see the account page')
def should_see_account_page():
   Do something
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you're saying is you want to run all of your tests once with USER1, and once again with USER2, then what you're looking for is [parametrized tests](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/parametrize.html).

Essentially, you define your test once. You then define a group of variables in tuples, with an optional set of IDs, and pytest will then run that test once for each set of parameters.

Let's take a basic example.

```
addition(a, b):
    return a + b

def test_addition(a, b, expected):
    assert addition(a, b) == expected
```

Rather than define the test over and over with different parameters, like:

```
def test_addition():
    a = 2
    b = 2
    expected = 4
    assert addition(a, b) == expected

def test_addition():
    a = -2
    b = -2
    expected = -4
    assert addition(a, b) == expected
```

You can use the `pytest.mark.parametrize` decorator:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize('a, b, expected', ((2, 2, 4), (-2, -2, -4)))
def test_addition(a, b, expected):
    assert addition(a, b) == expected
```

When you run this test, you'll see the following output.

```
$ pytest -v test_addition.py
====================================== test session starts =======================================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.2, pytest-3.2.2, py-1.4.34, pluggy-0.4.0 -- /home/stackoverflow
cachedir: .cache
rootdir: /home/stackoverflow, inifile:
collected 2 items                                                                                 

test_addition.py::test_addition[2-2-4] PASSED
test_addition.py::test_addition[-2--2--4] PASSED

==================================== 2 passed in 0.01 seconds ====================================
```

So, to go back to your question, you want to do something like this:

```
import pytest

USER1 = 'John'
USER2 = 'Peter'

@pytest.mark.parametrize('user', ((USER1), (USER2)))
def test_something(user):
    # Do something with ``user``
    # Test runs twice - once with USER1, once with USER2
    pass
```

---

If your list was long, it would be better to use a [fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html).

```
users_to_test = {
    'params': ((USER1), (USER2)),
    'ids': ['test first user', 'test second user']
}

@pytest.fixture(**users_to_test, scope='function')
def params_for_test_something(request):
    return request.param

def test_something(params_for_test_something):
    user = params_for_test_something[0]
    pass
```

I think this is a much more manageable way of doing things. You can also parametrize your fixtures, so the magic goes really really deep.